# Why can't an answer include material from a previous answer?

Tags: discussion

This answer of mine was deleted by a moderator (Caleb) for containing preexisting material.

[Does Revelation 3:20 refer to individuals or a whole church (Laodicea)?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/27875/does-revelation-320-refer-to-individuals-or-a-whole-church-laodicea/38365?r=SearchResults&s=1|21.7318#38365)

I was told it was because it was a duplicate answer (which it was not) but I had adapted it from another answer so it contained mostly preexisting material.

But it answers the question accurately. These are Caleb's comments:

> This is the answer to a different question. Please don't post duplicate answers. If the same answer would answer two different questions then the questions should be closed as duplicates. – Caleb

As I understand his comment there is a problem with the post being a duplicate so my answer is being deleted as a solution. Is that um, "fair"? Does that reach the goals of this site better than a little repetition?

Comment: Related meta-meta post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions

Comment: Helpful and related but not my question.

Answer (score 5):

So first thing to be aware (if you're not already) is that the Community User automatically flags answers that are duplicates. I believe you originally copied the answer you link in your question as is to the other question - which is when it was flagged - and then subsequently you edited it to add a third section.

The reason that Stack Exchange has decided to automatically flag these is because in most cases where answers are identical there is something wrong. There are several possibilities:

- Someone accidentally double posted on the same question (obviously not the case here)
- The questions are duplicates such that the answer applies to both, in which case the preferred way to handle is to Vote to Close the duplicate question rather than posting a duplicate answer.
- While the questions are indeed different questions, the answer being given for both is not really specifically targeted at that question.

In my view your answer probably falls into the third category here. It's hard to imagine a good answer that is able to specifically address both the question of "Is the invitation to dine a reference to the Eucharist?" and the question "Is this invitation directed to an individual person or the church as a collective?", particularly when the OP is asking the second to be addressed specifically in terms of the underlying Greek. Even if the you seek to answer the second on the basis of your answer to the first, it would be better in my opinion to simply link to your other answer and then build your argument from there.

Comment: I tried that in answer to your version of a question for which I had an answer but it was changed to a comment which was not acceptable to me

Comment: Obviously nobody wants to address the real problem so let's just drop the discussion

Comment: @Ruminator - I have numerous answers that have lifted wholly or partially from another of my answers. No one has ever criticized any of these, however I am sure to cross-link and I usually at least rewrite the intro and summary. If your answer is short enough to be converted to a comment, then it shouldn't be an answer. Answers should be thoughtful and do at least some work and it is doubtful that an answer that is less than 500 words is successful at doing that.